# docker swarm service all replicas in one node

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I created a swarm with 4 node, 2 manager, 2 worker. one of the manager is in drain mode.
i am running 3 replicas of an nginx based web app built using vue.js only, no backend, no db.
now when i run the `docker service ls` command, i get the following:

```
$ docker service ls
ID                  NAME                  MODE                REPLICAS  
4nk9b9zm3rlp        friendly_hugle        replicated          0/3                    
qwqj07gu03zu        intelligent_khayyam   replicated          0/3                    
37tol0zrs82n        strange_hodgkin       replicated          0/3                    
dvl4r0vimqtd        suspicious_greider    replicated          3/3
```

why all my replicas are running on one node (3/3)? Just started learning docker.

Answer (score -1):

run the command,Check whether the running node is in normal state,

```
docker node ls
docker service ps strange_hodgkin
```